# User password is invalid after some days

Tags: 20.04, password

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 server. Every now and then I access the server locally (via an attached screen) for doing updates etc. As soon as some days passed in-between, I can not access my usual user via the given password (access denied). I always need to log in to the root user and reset the normal users password, log out from root and can then log in to the normal user. I am very confident, that it is the correct password. Is there any way that the password could be time validated?
How can I permanently set the normal users password?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: User passwords don't spontaneously change on their own. Who else uses the device?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that the password could be time validated?

Yes. There is an option for that BUT the message it then shows is different. Along the lines of "You are required to change your password immediately (password expired)". And there is a command that tells you if it can expire or it is expired (and the last time it changed)

```
chage -l $USER
```

It will tell you:

```
Last password change                    : {date}
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

so you can confirm when it changed, and if it expires, or has expired.

If your password can expire:

```
chage -E -1 $USER
```

- `-1` disables it. Can also be 2029-01-01 and it expires then.
- $USER is replaced by your current account. replace it by the actual name and add sudo at the front if you need it for other users.
- do make sure you do not have caps lock active. I know I do that a lot :)
- if this is not the solution to your problem and you are the only admin there is a worst case scenario possible: it could be that the system is compromised. ALSO change the `sudo` password (I assume you mean `sudo` and not `root` since we do not use that in Ubuntu).